# PHP validation logic

Tags: php, validation

I have a form for submitting user data. 
The validation for it is currently flawed and I am looking for the best way to 
correct it.

The form contains the 3 text fields, 1 radio button & 3 drop down lists.

The code:

```
$titleError = "";
$durationError = "";
$directorError = "";
$certError = "";
$dateError = "";


//Array with all the possible error messages so far:
$errors = array("title"=>"Title is required",
            "duration"=>"Title duration is required",
            "durationCheck"=>"Duration must be an integer value",
            "director"=>"Title Director is required",
            "directorCheck"=>"Director must be an alphabetic value",
            "certification"=>"Title certification is required",
            "date"=>"Invalid date"
            );



if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $submit = ($_POST['submit']);

            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $duration = $_POST['duration'];
            $director = $_POST['director'];


            //If any of the (title, duration, director) are empty or if any of the (day, month, year) are unchanged or if the cert isn't set i.e radio button checked
            //This if will make sure that all the fields are filled before submitting, however if all fields ARE filled it will of course bypass the checks inside the statement. Meaning the checks inside are only carried out when the user misses an input.
            if (empty($title) || empty($duration) || empty($director) || !isset($_POST['cert']) || ($_POST['day'] == "DD") || ($_POST['month'] == "MM") || ($_POST['year'] == "YYYY")){

                    if (empty($title)) { $titleError =$errors['title'];}
                    if (empty($duration)) { $durationError = $errors['duration'];} else if (!is_int($duration)) {$durationError = $errors['durationCheck']; } 
                    if (empty($director)) {$directorError = $errors['director'];} else if (!ctype_alpha($director)) {$directorError = $errors['directorCheck']; } 
                    if (empty($_POST['cert'])) {$certError = $errors['certification'];}
                    if (($_POST['day'] == "DD") || ($_POST['month'] == "MM") || ($_POST['year'] == "YYYY")) {$dateError = $errors['date'];}  



            } else {

                        //Check if duration entered is an integer
                        //if (is_int($duration) && ctype_alpha($director)) 

                                $cert = $_POST['cert'];
                                $day = $_POST['day'];
                                $month = $_POST['month'];
                                $year = $_POST['year'];
                                $day = convertToTwoDigit($day);
                                $month = convertToTwoDigit($month);


                                $date = $year."/".$month."/".$day;


                                echo "<br>Title: ".$title."</br>"."Duration: ".$duration."</br>"."Director: ".$director."</br>"."Cert: ".$cert."</br>Relesed on: ".$date;

                                //Add values into database: 

                                if ($insert = $db->query("
                                INSERT INTO titles (cert, filmtitle, releaseDate, filmDuration, director) VALUES ('$cert', '$title', '$date', '$duration', '$director')
                                ")){
                                    echo "You have added a film";
                                } else {
                                    echo "Error adding";
                                }

        }


}
```

Comment: "currently flawed" you have to give us a little ore to go on

Comment: I dont understand your question, is your code not working properly? or Are you looking to make it more efficient?

Comment: @Dagon, basically it's the main if statement. It will allow the user to submit data without checks as long as all fields are filled. The individual field checks are only performed when at least one field is missing. I am looking for the best approach to fix that.

Comment: The comment above if statement explains the issue

Comment: apologies for lack of clarity

Answer (score 0):

Your validation logic is indeed flawed. You check to see whether all values are present and only validate if one of them is missing!
See the problem? You need to validate if all of them are present instead.
An easier solution in your case is to handle each field in turn like this:

```
<?php
// this is very procedural, but that's another matter

// somewhere to store errors as you find them
$errors = array();

if (!isset($_POST['var1')) {
    $errors[] = 'Var 1 missing';
} else {
    // validate - lets pretend it must be a positive integer greater than 10
    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
    if (!is_numeric($var1) || $var1 < 0 || $var1 > 10) {
        $errors[] = 'Var 1 out of range';
    }
}

// next one
if (!isset($_POST['var2')) {
    $errors[] = 'Var 2 missing';
} else {
    // validate - lets pretend it must be the char 'a', 'b' or 'c'
    $var2 = $_POST['var2'];
    if ($var2 !== 'a' && $var2 !== 'b' && $var2 !== 'c') {
        $errors[] = 'Var 2 out of range';
    }
}

//etc...

// $errors will be empty if everything was fine
if (empty($errors) {
    // do stuff with the validated vars
} else {
    // send the errors back to the user
}
```